# using Ansible for netstat command and format on playbook

Tags: python, linux, unix, ansible

Using ansible to run a nestat command and then using `grep` to get an IP address

but when it runs throught the playbook it hard to read off of terminal. Looks like the format is off but also the `IP` address isnt coming back.

I have tested the command on the server of choice and it does what its meant to do

```
 - name: netstat check
       command: netstat -tulnp | awk grep -e 'PADDRESS HERE'
       register: netstat
 - debug: msg="{{netstat.stdout}}"
```

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below to get the format right

```
- debug: msg="{{netstat.stdout_lines}}"
```